# Show that the intersection of all subfields is the prime field

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

I am currently trying to prove that, given that $K$ is a field and $k\subset K$ is its prime-field, that
\begin{equation}
k =\bigcap_{\small{\overline{K} \text{ subfield of } K}}\overline{K}.
\end{equation}

Here are my definitions:

If the characteristic of $K$ is $0$: There is a unique $f:\mathbb{Q}\rightarrow K$ which is injective.

If the characteristic of $K$ is $p$: There is a unique $f:\mathbb{Z}/ p\mathbb{Z}\ \rightarrow K$ which is injective.

The prime subfield is defined as Im$(f)$, which I think would mean that $\mathbb{Q}\cong k$ or $\mathbb{Z}/ p\mathbb{Z}\cong k$ (depending on the characteristic of $K$).

Now to my question: Do I need to look at both cases and construct the smallest possible subfield of $K$? In the first case this would be $\mathbb{Q}$ because every field needs to contain {$0,1$} which we can build up to $\mathbb{Q}$. Where do I need the isomorphism from $k$ to $\mathbb{Z}/ p\mathbb{Z}$ or $\mathbb{Q}$ ? I am having troubles with my intuition when it comes to algebra, so any push into the right direction would be appreciated.

Comment: It's the slash, not the backslash :-) Yes, your intuition here is correct, a field must contain 0 and 1, and thus all finite sums of 1's. There may be a finite number of them (char = $p$) and an infinite number. The existence of $f$'s means that every field of characteristic $p$ has to contain an isomorphic copy of $\Bbb Z /p\Bbb Z$, and of char 0, a copy of $\Bbb Q$. A prime field can't contain a lesser field in it.

Comment: That's great to hear, thank you! Always nice to get some confirmation :). Thank you for pointing the backslash out.